# Google Distance Matrix and Google Places in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-distancematrix-api

How can I get the time duration and the distance between my current location and the place from google places api? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since a sensitive user data, such as your current location is included, it is recommended that you post a Google Maps Distance Matrix API request using HTTPS.

You may post your request in the following form:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters`

Sample request to get the distance and duration between two locations with the following parameters:

- output: JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)
- origin: Seattle, WA, USA
- destination: San Francisco, CA, USA
- mode: Driving
- language: English

Can be written in the following form:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=driving&language=en`

Helpful information regarding the Google Maps Distance Matrix API service and request parameters to be used can be found in [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#Introduction).